# why does this program print only 0's?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to solve boolean expressions using `k-map`. I am using the logic that accepts the minterms from the user and checks if the minterms matches the corresponding element in an array that is initialised by me and if it does, make that element `1` and if it doesn't, make it `0`. My program makes all the elements `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void table(){
    printf("\n|-------------------------------------|");
    printf("\n|variables|Minterms|Term|Maxterms|Term|");
    printf("\n|---------|--------|----|--------|----|");
    printf("\n| 0| 0 | 0|x'.y'.z'| m0 |x+y+z   | M0 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 0 | 1|x'.y'.z | m1 |x+y+z'  | M1 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 1 | 0|x'.y.z' | m2 |x+y'+z  | M2 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 1 | 1|x'.y.z  | m3 |x+y'+z' | M3 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 0 | 0|x.y'.z' | m4 |x'+y+z  | M4 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 0 | 1|x.y'.z  | m5 |x'+y+z' | M5 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 1 | 0|x.y.z'  | m6 |x'+y'+z | M6 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 1 | 1|x.y.z   | m7 |x'+y'+z'| M7 |");
    printf("\n|-------------------------------------|");
}
void main()
{   int i,j,k,n,nm,ochoice,minterms[10],kmap[4][4]={0,1,3,2,
                                                4,5,7,6,
                                                12,13,15,14,
                                                8,9,11,10};
    char v[6];
    printf("\t\t\tK-MAP");
    printf("\n\t\t\t-----");
    printf("\nEnter no of variables(3or4):");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the variables: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   printf("\nEnter variable %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n1.SOP");
    printf("\n2.POS");
    printf("\nEnter the required output form(1or2):-");
    scanf("%d",&ochoice);
    switch(ochoice)
    {case 1 :{system("cls");
              table();
              printf("\nEnter the number of minterms : ");
              scanf("%d",&nm);
              printf("\nEnter the corresponding minterms number from the table above : ");
              for(i=0;i<nm;i++)
              {
                  printf("\nEnter Minterm %d:",i+1);
                  scanf("%d",&minterms[i]);

              }

              for(i=0;i<4;i++)
              {
                  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                  {
                      for(k=0;k<nm;k++){
                        if(kmap[i][j]==minterms[k]){
                            kmap[i][j]=1;
                        }
                        else{
                            kmap[i][j]=0;
                        }
                      }
                  }
              }
             for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    printf("\n");
                for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                    printf(" %d ",kmap[i][j]);
                }
             }
             break;
             }
    }

}
```

```
Enter the number of minterms :4
Enter minterm 1:1
Enter minterm 2:5
Enter minterm 3:4
Enter minterm 4:12
output:-0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
expexted output:-0 1 0 0
                 1 1 0 0
                 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0
```

NB:-the program works fine with only one minterm

Comment: Please correct the indentation of you code, its really hard to read and the code you showed here is incomplete.

Comment: So you are comparing the input data with `kmap[][]` elements and then setting the very same elements within a loop to `0` or `1` and are then suprised why they don't equal the input data?? Note that each element of `kmap[i][j]` is compared and set `nm` times.

Comment: Oh - oops - you've now changed the code.

Comment: Well the same applies. It's like shifting sand trying to compare values that are being changed `nm` times each and expecting sense.

Comment: Put it this way: one of your input values is `5` and `kmap[1][1]` is `5`. But by the time you check it, you have already changed `kmap[1][1]` to `0` because it didn't match another value.

Comment: oh,i get it know,thanks for explaining,let me think about something to solve this and will write back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pointed out by @Weather Vane
i corrected it by making another array and doing the changes in it,
here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void table(){
    printf("\n|-------------------------------------|");
    printf("\n|variables|Minterms|Term|Maxterms|Term|");
    printf("\n|---------|--------|----|--------|----|");
    printf("\n| 0| 0 | 0|x'.y'.z'| m0 |x+y+z   | M0 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 0 | 1|x'.y'.z | m1 |x+y+z'  | M1 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 1 | 0|x'.y.z' | m2 |x+y'+z  | M2 |");
    printf("\n| 0| 1 | 1|x'.y.z  | m3 |x+y'+z' | M3 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 0 | 0|x.y'.z' | m4 |x'+y+z  | M4 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 0 | 1|x.y'.z  | m5 |x'+y+z' | M5 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 1 | 0|x.y.z'  | m6 |x'+y'+z | M6 |");
    printf("\n| 1| 1 | 1|x.y.z   | m7 |x'+y'+z'| M7 |");
    printf("\n|-------------------------------------|");
}
void main()
{   int i,j,k,n,nm,ochoice,minterms[10],kmap[4][4]={0,1,3,2,
                                                4,5,7,6,
                                                12,13,15,14,
                                                8,9,11,10};
    int k2map[4][4]={0,0,0,0,
                     0,0,0,0,
                     0,0,0,0,
                     0,0,0,0,};

    char v[6];
    printf("\t\t\tK-MAP");
    printf("\n\t\t\t-----");
    printf("\nEnter no of variables(3or4):");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the variables: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   printf("\nEnter variable %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n1.SOP");
    printf("\n2.POS");
    printf("\nEnter the required output form(1or2):-");
    scanf("%d",&ochoice);
    switch(ochoice)
    {case 1 :{system("cls");
              table();
              printf("\nEnter the number of minterms : ");
              scanf("%d",&nm);
              printf("\nEnter the corresponding minterms number from the table above : ");
              for(i=0;i<nm;i++)
              {
                  printf("\nEnter Minterm %d:",i+1);
                  scanf("%d",&minterms[i]);

              }

              for(i=0;i<4;i++)
              {
                  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                  {
                      for(k=0;k<nm;k++){
                        if(kmap[i][j]==minterms[k]){
                            k2map[i][j]=1;

                        }
                      }
                  }
              }
             for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    printf("\n");
                for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                    printf(" %d ",k2map[i][j]);
                }
             }
             break;
             }
    }

}
```